# Overpass API Query for Superroutes in OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I have a [superroute](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation:superroute) in OpenStreetMap which defines a network of mountain bike trails ([12425503](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/12425503)) and it contains member routes such as ([8467869](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/8467869)).

I'm trying to write an Overpass QL query for the superroute, which returns the member routes, relations, etc.

How do I write a query to do this?

This query successfully returns 8467869:

```
(
  relation["type"="route"]["ref"="EPIC"](46.458673519829,-87.67682075500488,46.52975664934808,-87.58721351623535);
);
way(r);
(._;>>;);
out body;
```

But this returns nothing:

```
(
  relation["type"="superroute"]["ref"="RAMBA"](46.458673519829,-87.67682075500488,46.52975664934808,-87.58721351623535);
);
way(r);
(._;>>;);
out body;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a known limitation, see https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/293

You can only query for those superroutes without the bounding box filter as described here: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/50752/how-do-i-get-route_master-and-its-children-via-overpass-ql-in-overpass-turbo

As a side note: please note that the use of relations (in this case the superroute) as categories is not recommended and in fact discouraged, see https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relations_are_not_categories

Comment: Thanks for that info. I found that bug as well, in the linked thread.

The wiki post you link to actually calls out what this relation is used for as a good use: aggregating cycling routes. In this case it's an superroute aggregating a number of other local cycling routes under the parent network.

Comment: Typically you would add a tag like "operator=RAMBA" and maybe "operator:website" to each single relation and remove the superroute. It's really not needed.

Comment: There are a number of places where one trail advocacy organization (in some cases this may be the operator, in others it wouldn't) spans multiple parks across a relatively wide geographical region. And each of those parks contains multiple trails, each trail which would be its own relation.

I think it makes sense to have a superroute to aggregate all the trails within a given park, otherwise there's no unique identifier for the trail network within that park. Querying on everything for that operator would be too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer thanks to [this](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/50752/how-do-i-get-route_master-and-its-children-via-overpass-ql-in-overpass-turbo).

Turns out that superroutes don't have geometry of their own. So expanding the query, then setting a bbox for the child relations, does the trick:

```
(
  rel["type"="superroute"]["ref"="RAMBA"];
);
(rel(r)({{bbox}});>;);
out body;
```